# Running Multiple Tasks parallely results in System.AggregateException

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, task

I am fetching data from an API with different dataset-identifiers as a query parameters. Earlier I tried a synchronous approach but its taking too much time.So I decided to create Tasks dynamically inside a `foreach` loop for every dataset-identifier. Here is the code that I have written

```
foreach (var dataset in datasets)
{
    Task task = new Task(() =>
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var urlParameters = $"?apikey={apiKey}&dataset={dataset}";
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);
            HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(urlParameters).Result;
            var yearlyDatasetResult = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            var datasetCsvHeader = yearlyDatasetResult.Split(new[] { '\r', '\n' })
                .FirstOrDefault();
            var headers = datasetCsvHeader.Split(';');
            if (csvHeaders.Length < headers.Length)
                csvHeaders = headers;

            var content = yearlyDatasetResult.Substring(datasetCsvHeader.Length);
            using (var file = new StreamWriter("C:\\xxxx\\xxxx\\source\\"
                + $"repos\\xxxx\\CSV\\{dataset}.csv"))
            {
                file.WriteLine(content);
            }
        }
    });

    task.Start();
    tasksToWait.Add(task);
}

Task.WaitAll(tasksToWait.ToArray());
Console.WriteLine("All tasks completed");
```

My goal is to fetch all the CSV files and then write to my system without the headers via parallel running tasks, but I am getting `System.AggregateException`. Could it be because of the blocking nature of this line?

```
HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(urlParameters).Result;
```

I am not able to guess the reason for this  kind of exception, I do know that one of the tasks is failing and that's why I am getting this aggregated exception and that's the nature of `Task.WaitAll(...)`, What could be the possible solution to this ?

Comment: An AggregateException should contain one or more other exceptions that tell you exactly what the issue is, but yeah, I'd guess it's the blocking calls and the fact that you don't even `await` the `Task.WaitAll`.  You should really commit to using async/await.

Comment: the exception is happening during the execution of this line?
`HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(urlParameters).Result;`

Comment: @RichárdBaldauf I am just guessing that even I am not sure

Comment: @ShubhamTiwari ah okay. To figure this out I'm suggesting Christopher answer below. Using the async/await feautre would be usefull to identify the source of the exception ^.^

Answer (score 3):

> Running Multiple Tasks parallely results in System.AggregateException

That is a slightly incorrect assesment. Your code is throwing Exceptions. `AggregateException` is only there so you do not ignore them by accident.

Multtiasking is notoriously good at swallowing Exceptions. And as that is the only way to communicate them, each task in a Execution line might throw Exceptions and Exceptions should never be ignored, all Exceptions are collected and raised wrapped neatly into a `AggregateException`.

You goal is to figure out what those Exceptions are, to properly [classify them](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/) and then [properly handle them](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9538/Exception-Handling-Best-Practices-in-NET). Without the inner exceptions it is hard to say

Answer (score 2):

An [`AggregateException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.aggregateexception) is just a bag that contains other exceptions. You can access these exceptions through the property [`InnerExceptions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.aggregateexception.innerexceptions):

```
try
{
    Task.WaitAll(tasksToWait.ToArray());
    Console.WriteLine("All tasks completed");
}
catch (AggregateException aex)
{
    foreach (var ex in aex.Flatten().InnerExceptions)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex);
    }
}
```

In the above example I used the method [`Flatten`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.aggregateexception.flatten) just in case there are nested `AggregateException`s, to flatten the tree.